# How to allow multiple concurrent users for r shiny app within local network

Tags: r, shiny

I built an R shiny app for my coworkers to use inside the company. They don't know anything about R and there is no way that I ask all of them to install R on their own machine. Therefore, I tried code:

`runApp(appDir = appdir,host="0.0.0.0", port = 5295)`

This successfully allow my coworkers to use the app. However, when multiple people use it at the same time, there will be interruptions. Is there a way to solve this problem besides spending money to get a R/Shiny server?

Comment: Probably note, but you can maybe turn you own computer into a server int he local network. There is a free version of shiny server: https://rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/ If you are familiar with docker you can easily deploy it with: https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny

Comment: The deployment method doesn't necessarily have an impact on concurrency. You'll need to use [futures / promises](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html) to ensure inter-session responsiveness.